# Vue.js $watch Not Working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

First, I have a Vue JS file --

```
export var myVue = new Vue({
    el: '#myApp',
    data: {
       myCoordinates: new Set() // simple integers
    },
    methods: {
        addCoordinates (c) {
            this.myCoordinates.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a another JS file that imports the Vue and does some plotting --

```
import { myVue } from './my_vue.js';

myVue.addCoordinates(42);

myVue.$watch('myCoordinates', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
    // plot the new coordinates
}, { deep: true });
```

The problem is the `myVue.$watch` does not fire -- I can see `myCoordinates` updated properly in Vue dev console, but `myVue.$watch` just doesn't get trigggered. And I can't test watch as Vue's native as I can't move the plotting part into `myVue` due to various restrictions.

The question is: What could have gone wrong in my case?

Edit: BTW, I'm using Webpack 4 to combine both JS files, would that have any side-effect?

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that the `watcher` has not been registered when you update your `coordinates` as show in your code (it's registered after you call `add` function). Similar to any kind of event listeners, you need to register the watcher / handler before the event happens for it to trigger.

With `Vue`, you can always register the watcher functions when you create a new Vue instance, for example:

```
export var myVue = new Vue({
    el: '#myApp',
    data: {
       myCoordinates: new Set() // simple integers
    },
    methods: {
        addCoordinates (c) {
            this.myCoordinates.add(c);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        myCoordinates: function(new, old) {
           console.log(new, old);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Vue2 watch does not support Set. See answers to my next question [Vue2 watch Set Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911030/vue2-watch-set-not-working)